# M2: Alternative way to display variations on product page

Tags: magento2

I'm managing a bicycle parts store on Magento 2. It has a couple of thousand configurable products with simple products attached to it. I'm displaying the configurable product's variations using Visual Swatches containing the variation's image.

While browsing the web, I came across a Dutch interior store that is using Magento 2 as well. However, they're using an alternative way of displaying variations on the configurable product. No dropdowns, no swatches. Instead, it's a list with all variations and separate cart buttons.

[image]

Is anybody familiar with this way of displaying? Is it a hidden Magento feature? A known module? I'm really interested, because it's much more efficient for my products.

Edit: site of sample image is: https://www.misterdesign.nl/collect-socket-low-hanglamp-ferm-living.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like a grouped product that consists of simple standalone products that are presented as a group.

See https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/catalog/product-create-grouped.html for details

Comment: I think it's just an old fashioned grouped product too...

Comment: I think you're right. The site has most likely made some custom changes to add 'Add to Cart' buttons per row, misleading me. Thank you for the link!

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a regular bundle product page

Please take a look on that one:

https://demo-m2.bird.eu/sprite-yoga-companion-kit.html

**Click on "Customize and Add to Cart" button it will scroll to the bottom and show you something similar you are looking for.*

Good Luck!

Comment: Hmmmm. There are some similarities, but I'm pretty positive the site in my screenshot is not using bundled products. Their html/css source code also does not show anything that points to bundled products. Seems to be actual variations, all with their own add to cart form.

Comment: Jason, could you share the site link? I wonder why/how they do that. Because each configurable product is associated with a single simple product. If you choose different options on the configurable page you must see two rows on the cart page, separating the simple products by rows, each one of them must have their variations like color and size rendered on the respective row. IN the screenshot that you shared they just allow change the quantity, for me the feature that better fits on your case is using bundle products.

Comment: Yes, here you go: https://www.misterdesign.nl/collect-socket-low-hanglamp-ferm-living.html I wasn't sure whether it's allowed to link to external sources, but apparently it is.

Comment: Jason, I think it is customization based on the list of the products, like upsell or related product. Please check the page(please scroll until related products):
https://magento2-demo.magebit.com/overnight-duffle.html
 The way how Magento includes the related products to the cart is different, you just needs to mark the option and the variable `related_product` will send the items id.
  Opening the code on browser inspector over the link that you provided I could identify that it is a list of forms that add the product to the cart. I was not able to understand the site's language.